# $text search with $or results in "No query solutions"

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This server side query in Meteor returns  "No query solutions"

```
$or: [
  {
   $text: {
    $search: searchValue,
    $caseSensitive: false,
    $diacriticSensitive: false
   }
  },
  {
    content: {$regex: re}
  } 
]
```

Comment: [To use a $text query in an $or expression, all clauses in the $or array must be indexed.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) Is it so in your Mongo?

Comment: Yes it is, I am searching the same field. content is indexed as text with OrbiterCMSArticles._ensureIndex({title: "text", content: "text", subtitle: "text"});

Comment: What happens when you remove the regex part or the $text part ?

Comment: Does it work when you use it via `OrbiterCMSArticles.rawCollection().find(query)` ?

Comment: If I remove either part of the or condition, it works.

Comment: No, it does work either with rawCollection ("Error: No query solutions")

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, but it turned out that the issue for me was that I was not waiting for the indexes to be built.

Answer (score 1):

You must to create text indexes to map each element you wanna search.
Example:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ element1: "text",
                            element2:'text' })
```

"To use a $text query in an $or expression, all clauses in the $or array must be indexed." 
Restrictions are defined at [$text behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#behavior)

Comment: As said in the comments, that was not that. The field I was searching was already indexed. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was creating a non-text index on all the fields that you are doing the $regex search on. A simple ascending or descending index should do the trick!